# How to pass context to a React/jsx view?

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I'm new to React, and I'm trying to figure out some basics. In other template engines such as EJS or Jade, you are able to pass in a context variable when you are rendering the view file in your routes/controller file. However, I have not found any way to do this with React/jsx. I should note that I am working with Express.

I am actually uncertain if jsx is a view engine, or if React somehow was one built in. In either case, I do not know how to pass context from the server to the view file.

For example, if I wanted to load profile information (that is stored on the server/backend), how would I pass that to my front end jsx view file in React/jsx?

Answer (score 2):

that's simple. There is a mess in MVC terminology, but I think it would be okay to say that React component is not just the "View", but "View + Controller".

As a direct analogy to the templating engines, component's `render()` function is your template. And `component.state` (which is local to the component) and `component.props` (arguments received from the upper component) both can be used as a "context".

If you want some really close analogy to the React component in the conservative part of the JS world, it's Backbone's `View` (which is again the view + controller if we use original MVC terminology; as I told - it's a mess). Conceptually, it's the same thing. JSX is used in `render()` instead of `EJS` (or whatever), that's it.

Btw, React's `context` concept is something different. Think of it as
props which are visible to the whole component subtree starting from
the component where the `context` is exposed.

> For example, if I wanted to load profile information (that is stored on the server/backend), how would I pass that to my front end jsx view file in React/jsx?

In the simplest case, you create the top-level React component, which would load the stuff you need on mount (`componentWillMount()`), put it to its local `state` when you'll receive the response from server (`this.setState(...)`), and pass elements of its state (`this.state`) down to the subcomponents as props (`<List items={ this.state.items } />`) in its `render()` function.

Whenever `state` is modified with `this.setState(...)`, the whole component subtree will render again. That's how it works. In the simplest case.